# Is there an iPod SDK?

Tags: iphone, ipod

Is it possible to write applications for the iPod and iPod Nano platforms, i.e. not iPhone / iPod Touch?

Some iPod 'Click Wheel' games are available on iTunes, but I can't find any developer documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe game publishers had to work directly with Apple on "classic" iPod applications - [here's](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/ea-mobile-on-ipod-game-development/) an article with an EA dev.

*Our talented teams here at EA Mobile first develop the games and then we work with Apple to do the final integration and testing on the iPod. To get ready for the launch, some of us practically lived in Cupertino. We even had to maintain the same level of secrecy while we were at Apple headquarters.*

Answer (score 6):

According to Wikipedia, there is no *publicly available* iPod SDK.*

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_game)

*I know wikipedia is not the most reliable source, but it seems to have the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know, there are some firms who have a licence for building iPod (Nano) apps. But for individuals, this isn't the case. However the iPod (nano) isn't the most intresting platform. The controls are verry limited and I've heared the clock speed isn't that extremly fast so big apps will not run that nice.